# LXC implementation with Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, lxc

I am new to Docker although I have used Linux containers in past.
Can anyone explain how exactly Docker uses LXC (architecture would be very useful)?

Comment: Since the release of version 0.9, it uses `libcontainer` by default which you can find [here](https://github.com/docker/libcontainer).

Comment: I want to install docker in my ubuntu-14.04 and tried to install docker from, http://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/ . I followed the steps given in mentioned link but when I run the #apt-get install lxc-docker command , I have got error :"Unable to locate package lxc-docker" . Please guide me to install docker in machine and create docker image.